# What is a simple nonlinear and noninvertible equation?

Tags: nonlinear-system, computational-mathematics

I am taking a computational physics course and my prof asked us to find a simple nonlinear and noninvertible equation. I have no clue where to even start with this question. By the way this is not an actual assignment he was just not able to think of any on his own.

Comment: You mean like $y=x^2$?

Comment: What do you mean by noninvertible, i.e. noninvertible on the entire domain or just a subset? $x^2$ is not invertible at 0.

Comment: noninvertible on the entire domain

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$ is not invertible on $(-\infty, \infty)$.